# Can an instance within a Spring controller become null?

Tags: java, spring, controller

I have a Spring servlet that requires an instance variable to be shared among different methods :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
public class MyController{

    private RenderRequest request;

    @RenderMapping
    public String renderPage(final RenderRequest request) {
        this.request= request;
        return "mypage";
    }

@ResourceMapping(value = "getItems")
    public void getItems() {

          //Code to get and return items which uses the RenderRequest object set in method renderPage
}

}
```

The renderPage method is always called when the page is rendered so the RenderRequest instance will always be set and cannot be null. Is my thinking correct? I'm concerned that the RenderRequest instance can somehow become null ?

Comment: Depends what calls `renderPage()` and with what argument.

Comment: do you want `renderPage` method to be called before processing every request?

Comment: @Debojit Saikia no, it is just called to render the view page, once the view page is loaded getItems can be called as a separate request from the view page.

Comment: Can `renderPage` be called with a `null` value for `request`?

Comment: @GriffeyDog renderPage cannot be called with a null value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `renderPage` method gets called, it will set the value for `RenderRequest`:

```
@RenderMapping
public String renderPage(final RenderRequest request) {
        this.request= request;
        return "mypage";
}
```

Now, as there will only be a single `MyController` instance (as you have not defined any scope for your bean and the default is singleton scope), you will always have your `RenderRequest` property available for your next method invocations.

Comment: Which also directly shows the problem with this approach. You are storing state inside a singleton... Now imagine 10 concurrent users, 1 instance of the controller, which `RenderRequest` is going to be there!

Comment: @M. Deinum thanks for posting this comment, the RenderRequest will be the same for every user since its a singleton which is a bug

Comment: Why would the `RenderRequest` be a singleton, the `MyController` is the singleton, the request changes per user/per request...

Comment: @M. Deinum when renderPage is called by a user1 the RenderRequest is set to user1. user2 then calls renderPage and RenderRequest is set to user2. If user1 then calls getItems the RenderRequest is set to user2, which is a bug

Comment: Yes it is, but it is not due to `RenderRequest` is a singleton but because of the `MyController` being a singleton. (Which is what your initial comment implies). Which is what I tried to clarify.

Comment: Agree with @M.Deinum. And its of course not a good idea to keep mutable instance variables in your singleton beans, because all the request threads will have access to the same instance variables. If you want a separate `RenderRequest` for each user, you can pass it as method parameter while calling `getItems`, instead of maintaining an instance variable.